# Use a string and output of function in C

Tags: c

I know that is possible to initialize a variable with multiple strings:

```
static const char *str = "hello\n"
                         "world!";
```

But I want to have the string output of a function into the string like this:

```
static const char *str = "hello\n"
                         foo()
                         "world!";
```

It is possible with the `#define` directive btw

```
#define STRING "some string"

static const char *str = "hello\n"
                         STRING
                         "world!";
```

Thanks for your help :)

I couldn't find anything about it. Only the `#define` directive.

But even I tried to call the function from `#define`, and I'm only able to print the variable alone.

Comment: If it's not a compile-time constant, then you need to dynamically construct it.

Comment: You can only do string concatenation like that with literals, not the result of calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be as simple as this because your first and last example use constant string that are known at compilation time, which enables the compiler to form one long single string just as if you had enclosed all of them inside a single pair of double quotes `" "`.

In C, strings are represented by pointers onto their first character, directly where they lie in memory, those string being terminated with a null code `'\0'` (which resolves into a byte set to zero : `0x00`).

Since there is no dedicated, managed object to handle strings, you need to allocate some space somewhere, then filling it with `strncpy()` or `strncat()`.

However, if your function directly returns a pointer toward a string that already exists somewhere, you may just ask `printf` to compose it for you:

```
printf("Hello %s world.", foo());
```

Comment: Ah you were a bit faster. Nice answer! Truly deserves my upvote.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, you do deserve mine as well (now done).

Answer (score 3):

That's impossible. What you call "initialize with multiple strings" isn't actually multiple strings. You're just building one large string *literal* (a compile-time constant explicitly written down) from multiple string literals.

Your preprocessor macro is just that: macro that gets replaced before the compiler even runs. Macros do not "exist" as code at runtime.

No. You need to use string concatenation. You'll have to call strlen on all strings you want to combine to get the individual lengths, add them up, allocate memory large enough for the sum +1 using malloc, then use `strcat` or `strncpy` to build the complete string.

C is **not** an intuitive, easy, safe or comfortable language when it comes to dealing with strings. Making mistakes when doing such string combinations and modifications is still today one of the, if not *the* most common source of security vulnerabilities. My private two cents here are: if you need to handle a lot of strings, use a programming language that has a proper string type, like rust, C++, go, python...

Answer (score 1):

`"hello\n" "world!"` is not concatenating the string. It is only a syntactic sugar when you define a **string literal**.

All "parts" of this string literal have to be known compile time.

you can use `#define` as macro definitions are textually replaced by the preprocessor before the actual compilation starts

```
#define H "Hello"
#define N "\n"
#define W "world"

char *x = H N W;
char *y = H
          N
          W;
```

After the preprocessing the compiler will compile:

```
char *x = "Hello" "\n" "world";
char *y = "Hello"
          "\n"
          "world";
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rb713c3c7

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone has said, string literal is handled by preprocessor at compile time and you need a runtime call to allocate memory and fill the memory with the string returned from the foo function. Here is some code to examine furhter.

The function `asprintf` allocates the memory and fills the value using formatted string literal. More on [asprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)

And always remember to free the string memory allocated by `asprintf`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING "some string"
char* foo() { return "some string"; }

int main()
{
  static const char *str1 = "hello\n" "world!";
  static char *str2;
  static const char *str3 = "hello\n" STRING "world!";
  printf( "str1\n%s\n", str1 );
  if ( asprintf( &str2, "hello\n%sworld!", foo() ) >= 0 )
  {
    printf( "str2\n%s\n", str2 );
    free(str2);
  }
  printf( "str3\n%s\n", str3 );
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting memory here; you're missing the crucial steps these other posts point out: str2 needs to point to some bigger, allocated specifically to for the confirmation of the other strings.

Comment: asprintf allocates the memory, free returns the memory

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, I mentally skipped the "a". Looked up asprintf: it's a GNU extension, do possibly not available here, since not actually part of C